# Webpack 4 with multiple entries and .css

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

So I am trying to migrate from webpack 1 to webpack 4.

This is my project structure:

```
src/
=entry/
==(entry_points related to .html files).js
=html/
==(names).html
=resources/
==css/
===(folders with css files)/
==fonts
===(font files)
==images/
===(a lot of images in folders)
```

So I succefully can export html files to the dist/ directory, but images and css is not exporting correctly.

My webpack 1 config(works fine): 
https://codepen.io/mepuduah/pen/QWwGELb

My webpack 4 config(doesn't work fine): https://codepen.io/mepuduah/pen/XWJNdop

My package.json scripts:
"build": "webpack --display-error-details",
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --content-base src --host 0.0.0.0"

Also package list:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-ttag": "^1.7.24",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "ejs-compiled-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ejs-render-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "ejs-webpack-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.10.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "globalize-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "hammer-slider": "^0.1.10",
    "hooks": "^0.3.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-minify-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "i18n-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "npm": "^6.13.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "vanilla-tilt": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-i18n": "^0.1.8",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "ejs-html": "^5.1.5",
    "ejs-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "ttag": "^1.7.21"
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a message of your failing build?

Comment: Nope, it is just load me html pages with js scripts, but without css. Also if I change --content-base to "dist/" it won't load not only css but images too